# Automapper with immutablelist

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

In Source class, I have IEnumurable Property. In the dest class, constructor takes the IEnumurable and converts to IImmutableList and assigns to a IEnumurable property.

Here is the code copied from program.cs in .Net 7.0:

```
// Copy and Paste to Program.cs in .Net 7 should work.
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassSource, ClassDestination>()
    .ConstructUsing(m => new ClassDestination(m.Nums));
    });

var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

var classSource = new ClassSource();

var classDestination = mapper.Map<ClassDestination>(classSource);

Console.WriteLine(classDestination.Nums.Count());

public class ClassSource
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Nums { get; init; } = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
}

public class ClassDestination
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Nums {get;}
    public ClassDestination(IEnumerable<int> ints)
    {
        //Nums = ints.ToList(); // This works
        Nums = ints.ToImmutableList(); // This throws exception
    }
}
```

Mapping fails with: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

If you let the code run, the full error message is:

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ClassSource -> ClassDestination
ClassSource -> ClassDestination

Type Map configuration:
ClassSource -> ClassDestination
ClassSource -> ClassDestination

Destination Member:
Nums

 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Clear()
   at lambda_method1(Closure, Object, ClassDestination, ResolutionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method1(Closure, Object, ClassDestination, ResolutionContext)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
Command terminated by signal 6
```

As you can see, it tries to call the method `.Clear()` of the immutable list in the target property `Nums`, which throws the `NotSupportedException`.

Because you already initialize the list through the constructor, you should explicitly ignore this member by adding the corresponding `.Ignore()` call to your mapping profile if you need to use `ConstructUsing()`:

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>#
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassSource, ClassDestination>()
        .ForMember(m => m.Nums, conf => conf.Ignore())
        .ConstructUsing(m => new ClassDestination(m.Nums));
});
```

If your target class is already fully initialized after calling the constructor, you should instead use `.ConvertUsing()`:

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>#
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassSource, ClassDestination>()
        .ConvertUsing(m => new ClassDestination(m.Nums));
});
```

Comment: Using `ConstructUsing` instead of `ConvertUsing` is a common mistake.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. By simply replacing `ConstructUsing()` with `ConvertUsing()`, no properties will be touched at all and the error is gone too. Updated answer.